# Tensorflow tf.losses.cosine_distance is greater than one

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm training a Neural network on Tensorflow and I'm using `tf.losses.cosine_distance` as a loss function.

The training proceeds well, but my concern is that during the training I have values of losses > 1. The cosine distance (if the input tensors are normalized to 1), should always be a value less than one? How is the loss calculated? Is it a sum of losses in a batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, [`tf.losses.cosine_distance`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/cosine_distance) has `reduction` argument, which equals to `reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS` by default:

```py
cosine_distance(
    labels,
    predictions,
    dim=None,
    weights=1.0,
    scope=None,
    loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES,
    reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS      # <-- Here
)
```

In this case, it computes the sum of all cosine distances across the batch. Change it to `Reduction.MEAN` and you'll have a mean loss across the batch, which is usually what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think cosine distance takes a value between 0 and 2, 0 when the two vectors are identical, 1 when the two vectors are orthogonal and 2 when they are opposite, you can try with some simple toy vectors.

Comment: "I think" isn't very useful